# What are town retainers?

Tags: shogun-2-total-war

I got this event asking if I wanted to execute a town's retainer or give him 1000 gold for his services.

[image: The Disgruntled Vassal]
*Osumi is the name of the region.*

It's a pretty fresh campaign, so I'm sure there is nothing in that city, and I was unaware of town retainers.

I don't understand the consequences of killing him or keeping him around. Who is this guy and what would happen if he were gone?

Comment: So far, all events I have encountered explained the effects of both choices. Since this one doesn't seem to have any effects aside from losing 1000 Koku, I am curious as well.

Comment: @nolonar it probably has an effect that triggers in a separate event after some period of time rather than immediately. Unfortunately its been a long time since I played so I don't remember what that effect is.

Comment: Many events - I'd even say most events - have a hidden aftereffect, as Lawton said. Even those that seem like a choice between equal alternatives come with hidden effects. If you don't have experience with the event, it's a good idea to take the moral high ground, aim for fairness and consider what the populace will like, since the opposite is likely to come with a drawbacks, ESPECIALLY if it looks like the much better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A retainer is basically a member of your government/organizational structure. They're not exactly modeled in the game but they're local officials keeping things running smoothly for you on a low level.

In this case if you have this vassal killed there is a chance at an event occurring a few turns later where his son leads a rebellion against you in the province where the initial event occurred.

So before killing him you should ask yourself if having a rebellion on your hands in that province can be dealt with easily and is worth the risk.

Answer (score -2):

I suspect that this sort of retainer has the potential to become a general.

Reading about daimyo, it seemed that their notable retainers were often generals themselves, controlling areas of their own. When coming across the idea of a "samurai general" (侍大将), which is a general directly under the supreme commandar, controlling an entire army (or [field army](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_army)), the famous historical example given was of a retainer belonging the Ouchi, which I recognized to be a non-playable clan from the game. [Sue Harukata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sue_Harukata) was famous because he was a great general who would eventually become daimyo by way of a coup.

With respect to the game, it seems reasonable that this sort of retainer, when holding enough loyalty, triggers the appointment of a new general. I also think they're much more important than I originally thought.

Comment: That's interesting but is it relevant to the game?

Comment: @Studoku Yes, I think so. For example, say you only have daughters. You'll need loyal retainers of this sort to promote to generals. Generals play a key role in the game not only benefiting armies, but are also needed to fill commissions. In this extreme case, it's good they can be adopted, or else who would succeed the the daimyo upon death? With the understanding of what these retainers are, it would seem unwise to execute them if you had a need for generals

Comment: @Studoku Mainly, I added this answer to offer an explanation of why generals appear. The widely held opinion has been it's a random event. So the execution option seems like a variable that could make it less likely for one to appear.

Comment: Why the down vote? :(